# Altium full-stack pad custom shape

Tags: altium, pad, gerber

I an currently trying to reconstruct a PCB in Altium from the Gerber files. So far, I have been able to import the Gerbers in a PCB document.

The existing Gerbers have through-hole pads that have a special shape in the inner layers (in green here):

[image]

I am able to set the pad in full-stack mode, but I am not sure on how I can achieve the pad shape of the old design (unless maybe create a custom pcb component).

[image]

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: The pad in green is called a _thermal_. The generation of thermals is controlled in the rules for planes when laying out a PCB.

Comment: This link will take you, even without a valid license, to an excellent (and official) Altium forum: https://forum.live.altium.com (where all you need to do is register for an account).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The green arcs are a thermal relief for a connection to a plane on that layer.

They are not part of the pad stack, or defined in the footprint.  They are created automatically when a via or through-hole pad has to connect to a plane layer or copper pour.

Comment: That would mean that there are planes on the two inner layers, but they are not shown in any way on the Gerbers. Is this a common thing with older PCBs? (Nobody knows in which software this board was done)

Comment: Or they are actually inverted layers (meaning the drawed shapes are removed from the copper) ?

Comment: My understanding is that in altium at least, what distiguishes a "signal layer" with pours from a "plane" layer is that on a signal layer the shapes represent copper while on a "plane" layer the shapes represent the absense of copper.

Comment: Yes, on a power or ground plane layer anything you draw is "not copper" - a hole in hte copper plane.